# Entity Framework Code First: Is there a way to automatically filter disabled rows from DbSets?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-5

In the data architecture I have to contend with, there are *no deletes*. Instead, all records have a nullable datetime2 that signals the record has been "disabled". This means that in the cases of direct selections on the entities, I'll always have to add in a check to see if the entity was disabled or not.

So far what I've come up with is just a simple extension method called `.Enabled()` that gets only the enabled rows. It seems effective so far, but it's also annoying that I have to type that in every case.

Surely someone else has skinned this cat before. Is there a better way to do this with Entity Framework I'm just not privy to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose you could do something like this

```
public class MyContext : DbContext
{
    public IDbSet<Thing> Things { get; set; }
    public IQueryable<Thing> EnabledThings
    {
        get
        {
            return Things.Where(t => t.Enabled);
        }
    }
}
```

or the same as an extension method (but on the context not the DbSet/queriable).

Personally in practice I actually do exactly as you have in your example and use `Things.Enabled().Whatever`

Comment: Yeah, I guess I'll stick with what I have. I was just hoping there was going to be someone that was like, "Oh, yeah, you just have to implement IAwesome and flip this Wiffle bit and this Waffle bit, and bango! You get what you need..." ... thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of anything native to Entity Framework. But normally when I run into this, I create an "repository" layer that I run most database transactions through. Then I create methods like `GetAll()` which returns all items with appropriate where statement in place to hide "deleted" items.